# Pandas read Excel by sheet name returns a dictionary instead of DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read a specific sheet from a multi-sheet Excel file. I am getting this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3276/178007814.py in <module>
      5 df = pd.read_excel("VMS.xlsx", sheet_name=['PS VMs'], usecols=['Name'])
      6 
----> 7 df.head()

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Looks like I am getting a dictionary from the sheet instead of the Dataframe! Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("VMS.xlsx", sheet_name=['PS VMs'], usecols=['Name'])

df.head()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is possible upload sample file, with sample data?

Comment: Thanks for comment, for sure I have only one sheet called `PS VMs`, and I am afraid I can not share the data with outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in documentation, Pandas will create a dictionary of frames if you provide a `list` (even with a single element)  or `None` (all sheets).

The following call does return a `dict`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel("Dummy.xlsx", sheet_name=[0])
```

In your code, change for:

```
df = pd.read_excel("VMS.xlsx", sheet_name='PS VMs', usecols=['Name'])
```

If you wish to have the frame directly. Or:

```
df["PS VMs"].head()
```

If you do need to have the sheet name it in a list.